# Store MySQL result in associative array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hi I am trying to store MySQL result into a global array

```
class db
{
 function CustomLoad($table_name,$Fields)
  {
     global $_MYSQL_DATA;

     $_MYSQL_DATA=array();

     $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table_name") or die(mysql_error());
     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
     {
       foreach($Fields as $r=>$key)
       {

        $_MYSQL_DATA[$r] = $row[$r];
       }

     }

   }
}
```

I am calling like this

```
$dbObj = new db();
$fields = array("FIELD_1"=>"FIELD 1","FIELD_2"=>"FIELD 2","FIELD_3"=>"FIELD  3","FIELD_4"=>"FIELD 4");
$dbObj->CustomLoad("registrations",$fields);

print_r($_MYSQL_DATA);
```

The problem is I am getting the last result only. like `Array ( [FIELD_1] => A [FIELD_2] => B [FIELD_3] => C [FIELD_4]=> D )`

Comment: You should really avoid using the `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated. Use PDO or `mysqli_*` functions instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the following:

```
 $_MYSQL_DATA = array(); // you should declare your variables, even if it's not mandatory
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)) // USE PDO or MySQLi !!!!!
 {
    $_MYSQL_DATA[] = $row;
 }
```

**Note**

The `[]` operator generates the smallest, positive, numeric key that is not used in your array.

**Examples:**

```
$array = array(0 => 'b', 1 => 'a');
$array[] = 'c'; // will place it in $array[2]

$array = array();
$array[] = 'a'; // will place in $array[0]
```

**And now** ... the rant about PDO / MySQLi (because I have to say it :P).

MySQL is officially deprecated since PHP 5.5, and it will no longer be maintained. You should consider porting your code to either MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: This answer is simpler and should do the same think as raheel shan answer

Comment: You're welcome. You should also start reading stuff at random from http://php.net, you find a lot of interesting stuff there.

Answer (score 1):

in foreach there should be $row not $Field. Also run a counter

```
$i=0;       
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
{
    foreach($row as $r=>$key)
    {
        $_MYSQL_DATA[$i][$r] = $key;
    }
    $i++;
}
```