# Php mysql query and echo with pagination

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a php script which gets data from a database by means of a mysql query, and shows the result of the query, divided into pages since there are more than 1,000 results.

I have been searching for an answer for how to do that, both in Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but for me each answer I have read just adds to my confusion. I guess I have lost the bigger view.

What I am looking for, is the simplest possible solution to dividing results from my mysql query into pages, preferably implemented into this script :

```
<?php

if (!$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mysql_password')) {
echo "Could not connect to mysql";
exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db('mysql_db', $link)) {
echo "Could not select database";
exit;
}

$sql    = "SELECT membername, city FROM table_members order by membername";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

$members = mysql_num_rows($result);

if (!$result) {
echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
echo "MySQL Error: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}



while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo  $row["membername"]. " -  " . $row["city"]. "<br>";
}


mysql_free_result($result);

echo "<br>";
echo "The community has  ";
echo "$members members \n";

?>
```

The script is quite simple and it works perfectly well, but I hope someone can help me change it to make it show the results page by page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your solution is simple Google find Php Pagination for me something like http://www.otallu.com/tutorials/simple-php-mysql-pagination/... : )

Comment: you are currently looping through your results using a while loop.  [add the results to an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14646470/store-mysql-result-in-associative-array) instead of displaying them in that loop.  then loop over the array and display the first 50 results for "page 1".  for "page 2", loop over your results array starting at record 51 and stopping at record 100, and so on.

Comment: I really appreciate your replies, but they don´t help me, at all. Like I wrote initially, when I encounter different suggestions how to solve this problem, I lose the general view of how the code works. I´m afraid I need more specific answers to how to change the code into something that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this once :) It has both demo and source code.
[Simple PHP pagination](http://www.freezecoders.com/2014/01/simple-pagination-using-php-mysql.html)

Comment: Hi Sonu. I followed the link, and tried to change the database name, server name, user name, table name and password accordingly, but I still experience errors like ' mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource ' . Can you be more specific ?

Comment: You are not connected with the mysql server. First check your mysql connect parameters. After that, check if mysql_query is returning true or false like this.  `code` $query=mysql_query("select * from pagination LIMIT $start, $limit"); if($query=== FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error());
}  In your code, Initialize $i=1 below $start  or it will give error

Comment: Problem solved ! How can I grant you credits ?

Comment: Great, It helped :) Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. (I think it's right below the arrows).
 It'll be right below the up and down vote arrows.

Comment: Check mark located - done ! :)